# Fire action in JPanel subclass

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I know how to use an `ActionListener` class to pick up an `actionPerformed` event - however, I've implemented my own JPanel object and something I can't work out is how I create an action and indicate it has been performed such that an external action listener can pick up on it. Specifically, I wish to intercept an action of an internal component, transform its `getSelectedValue()` and store this into a local variable available via a getter. I then want to indicate the change such that an external class can pick up on this and read the value and act upon it.

Any ideas? I imagine this is quite straightforward but I can't find what I'm looking for on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`Component.dispatchEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#dispatchEvent%28java.awt.AWTEvent%29) to dispatch event types that are already defined on your component.  If you add new event types, this may require a little more work.  See how [`AbstractButton`](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/AbstractButton.java.htm) ties into `JComponent`'s `listenerList` when adding the `ActionListener` options.

Comment: There's a nice overview of the approach in the `EventListenerList ` API, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Java) by extending [Observable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and making calls to the `setChanged` and `notifyObservers` methods.

Comment: +1 from me, that looks like a very good solution - I'll hang around and see if anyone can explain how to do it such that it triggers an actionlistener.

Comment: Many times it's hard to apply the Observer pattern with Swing components because usually your custom classes already extend some existing Swing component so they cannot also extend Observable.

Comment: @Shakedown: Alternatively, one can delegate to an instance of `Observable`.